# Unable to connect to a MySQL DB with peewee

Tags: mysql, python-3.6, pymysql, peewee

In PyCharm I created a MySQL schema using pymysql on my computer. Now I want to use Peewee to create tables and write the SQL queries. However, I always receive an error message (see below) when trying to connect to the DB.

The user has sufficient rights to create tables in the DB schema as it works flawlessly with pymysql (creating tables as well as the schema works fine).
I looked at similar questions on Stackoverflow and couldn't find a similar problem. Moreover, this problem wasn't experienced in any of the tutorials I looked at, so I'm not entirely sure what could be the culprit causing the error. Below is a minimal working example.

```
    from peewee import*
    import peewee

    user = 'root'
    password = 'root'
    db_name = 'peewee_demo'

    # The schema with the name 'peewee_demo' exists
    db = MySQLDatabase(db_name, user=user, passwd=password)


    class Book(peewee.Model):
        author = peewee.CharField()
        title = peewee.TextField()

        class Meta:
            database = db


    db.connect()  # Code fails here
    Book.create_table()
    book = Book(author="me", title='Peewee is cool')
    book.save()
    for book in Book.filter(author="me"):
        print(book.title)
```

I would expect the above code to connect to MySQL and then create a new table in the schema "peewee_demo". But instead, the code throws an error message when trying to connect to the DB:

> /usr/bin/python3.6: Relink '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol` clock_gettime'
>
> /usr/bin/python3.6: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1' with` /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
> Do you have any ideas how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whoa, you've got some shared-library issues or something. I'm not sure what linux distribution / hardware you're running, but looks like Python is not linking correctly against the shared libraries.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. I encountered similar errors earlier caused by some simple mistakes in my code (not related to peewee) leading to infinite recursion, so I was hoping that these errors above were also caused by some mistakes in my code, but if that's not the case I need to investigate. Thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: @coleifer Turns out that upgrading to Python 3.7 (probably setting up Python 3.6 from scratch should've also worked) solved the issue for me - thanks a lot for having pointed me in the right direction

Comment: @coleifer: if you turn your comment into a reply, I can upvote it and mark my problem as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @coleifer pointed out in his comment, the error was probably related to a shared library issue in Python. After setting up a new virtual environment and installing all required packages, everything runs perfectly fine.

I just added the answer to be able to close the question. If @coleifer converts his comment into an answer, I'll delete mine and accept his.